# Mapbox how to control map zooming speed in a mouse scroll

Tags: javascript, mapbox

I use `mapbox` (https://www.mapbox.com) and I want to make the zooming of the map slower during mouse scroll. Apparently, the API doc didn't have the speed control unless it is, for example, a flyTo() method or so.

I tried to control the speed of a zoom event that is triggered during zoom event but that didn't work as well. Could there be a way to control the speed of a zoom during mouse scroll zoom?

Answer (score 1):

I ended up solving this by myself. I disabled the mapbox scroll by

```
map.scrollWheelZoom.disable();
```

And then applied the standard jquery on wheel event on the div ID that holds the map.

```
$(document).on('wheel','#map', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta/120 > 0) {
      scrollZoomMap('up')
    }
    else{
      scrollZoomMap('down')
    }
}
```

and scollZoomMap function could look like this

```
function scrollZoomMap(dir){
 //console.log("dir : " + dir);  
 var newZoom = null;
 var debounce;
 var el = map; //the mapbox instance.
 latLng = el.getCenter();
 var latitude = latLng["lat"];
 var longitude = latLng["lng"];          
 var currentZoom = el.getZoom();
 if (debounce) clearTimeout(debounce);
   debounce = setTimeout(function(){
   debounce = null;
   if(dir == "up"){
     newZoom = currentZoom + 1;
   }else{
     newZoom = currentZoom - 1;
   }
   if( newZoom > 0 && newZoom < 22){
     //console.log("newZoom : " + newZoom);
     el.setView([latitude, longitude], newZoom);
    }             
   }, 300);              
 }
```

Comment: A solution through via the api is in the works: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-js/issues/4723